# saspy sas kernel not visible in jupyter

Tags: python, sas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can run  this code fine using a Python kernel:

```
import saspy
sas = saspy.SASsession()
sas
cars = sas.sasdata('cars', 'sashelp')
cars.head()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot chose a SAS kernel anymore. I re-installed saspy and the sas kernel and as you can see the sas kernel (?) is working from Python. This:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

only returns my python and r kernel:

```
Available kernels:
  ir         C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\ir
  python3    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Can I somehow refresh (?) manual register the sas kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine two reasons why this did not work out:

1. when you were installing sas_kernel, were you using the correct pip? (often in the same system you have python2 and python3, which both have separate package repositories)
2. have you tried manually to install it? I used the following command:

   ```
   jupyter kernelspec install <path_to_sas_kernel>
   ```

I was in similar situation, since I could not use pip in my environment (no internet connection allowed), I installed sas_kernel manually as a package (`python setup.py install`), and then installed sas_kernel using to my environment specific sas_kernel path:

```
jupyter kernelspec install .\newpackages\sas_kernel-2.1.7\sas_kernel
```

And it worked for me.
Hope this helps.